# Test for equality of arrays

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jestjs

How in the test to compare each value of the array, and not the entire array?
In my test, I compared the standardArray, but I need to compare List [1,2,3,4], but I'll get it so that the test does not lose its meaning.
Maybe somehow by the indexes or otherwise ...

```
import { List, Set } from "immutable"
let standardArray = List([1,2,3,4]);

export function mass(standardArray) {
  let mutatedArray = standardArray.map(x => x * 2);
  return mutatedArray;
};
```

test code:

```
import { List, Set, isImmutable, Record, Map } from "immutable"
import { mass } from "./sum";


test('aligning arrays', () => {
  let standardArray = List([1,2,3,4]);
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   expect(mass(standardArray)).toEqual(standardArray.map(x => x * 2));
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check each value you can try something like this:

```
test('values should match', () => {
  let originalArray = List([1,2,3,4]);
  let expectedResult = List([2,4,6,8]);
  let actuaResult = mass(originalArray);

  for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
   expect(expectedResult[i]).toEqual(actuaResult[i]);
  };
});
```